# How to get msg like 4 min ago in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I was tring to get msg like 4 min ago or 1 day ago in my web application i made a table in mysql and a field with TIMESTAMP type and default  2016-04-14 16:02:00 but this function is returning 3 hours ago which should be 10 min ago 
i tried setting time zone and echoing time which seems perfectly ok but return value has 3 hours ago

```
function timeAgo($timestamp){
    $datetime1=new DateTime("now");


    $datetime1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta')); 

    echo $datetime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "<br>";

    $datetime2=date_create($timestamp);
    echo $datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "<br>";                            

    $diff=date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);                            

    $timemsg='';
    if($diff->y > 0){
        $timemsg = $diff->y .' year'. ($diff->y > 1?"'s":'');

    }
    else if($diff->m > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->m . ' month'. ($diff->m > 1?"'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->d > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->d .' day'. ($diff->d > 1?"'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->h > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->h .' hour'.($diff->h > 1 ? "'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->i > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->i .' minute'. ($diff->i > 1?"'s":'');
    }
    else if($diff->s > 0){
     $timemsg = $diff->s .' second'. ($diff->s > 1?"'s":'');
    }
    $timemsg = $timemsg.' ago';
    return $timemsg;
}
```

and this is returning

```
2016-04-14 16:21:02
2016-04-14 16:02:00
3 hour's ago
```

The code is saying 3 hours which is not correct what went wrong?

Comment: Why can't you use a client side code like [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com)?

Comment: Are you deliberately not setting a timezone on `$datetime2` because you want to match it against local time of the server?

Comment: `$datetime2` is probably set to different timezone and then you make `date_diff` so when it compares them it 'converts' datetime2 to same timezone as datetime1. You can set `$datetime2` to the same timezode (Asia/Calcutta) and then it will be fine:)

Comment: I tried that as well but no luck server has the timezone of Asia/Calcutta 
I tryied to print the time as string on line 6 and in the out put I got
2016-04-14 16:21:02
2016-04-14 16:02:00
3 hour's ago
plz try this code its too confusing whats happning